# WP All Import - Update stock quantity from multiple Stock Locations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an XML feed that I use in WP All Import to update my products on my Woocommerce site.

I have two locations where stock is kept in my country - they are called wh1 and wh2 and in the XML feed they are called wh1stock and wh2stock.

I want to have them add up for the qty stock available for a product, e.g. if wh1 has 5 units and wh2 has 5 units the total stock qty should be displayed as 10 units.

I followed this code in my functions.php:

```
add_action('pmxi_saved_post', 'post_saved', 10, 1);

function post_saved($id) {

$original_stock = get_post_meta($id, '_stock', true); 
$new_stock = get_post_meta($id, '_custom_stock_placeholder', true);

$combined_stock= $original_stock + $new_stock;

update_post_meta($id, '_stock', $combined_stock);

}
```

And created the following custom fields in the WP All Import section:
[Custom Field Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZBpu.png)
and in the Woocommerce section I have the following settings:
[Woocommerce Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48hg8.png)

However this does not seem to work at all to add up the two stock locations...

Can someone perhaps help me with the correct settings/code please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with the same issue, the solution is to add the following into the WooCommerce section at Stock QTY:

```
[MATH({wh1stock[1]},"+",{wh2stock[1]})]
```

Hope this helps for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Brendon's solution didn't work for me, while this did:

```
[array_sum(array({wh1stock[1]},{wh2stock[1]}))]
```

Basically, I've used [WP All Import's inline PHP](https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/inline-php/), created an array of values, and summed them.